# SQL Select data if only data exist

Tags: sql

I created a register form and logging form with html, and I created a database for it, but when I insert invalid data (data that doesn't exist in database) to the logging form, It doesn't show an error, I want an error msg when I insert invalid data (data that doesn't exist in database), how i do it?

Comment: Show us your code....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you submit a form then first get username and password from logging form ,then make one method in which pass username and password.the method is boolean and check data from database using below query.

```
select * from table where username="abc" and password="abc";
```

if this query get record then data exist otherwise not.

Comment: although that scenario may work, I don't think it will resolve the question.  What if they want to prevent adding user "abc"... just because someone may put in an invalid password, you shouldn't be able to duplicate the "abc" user name.

Comment: `"abc"` refers to a column not to a character literal in SQL. So your query will fail unless there is a column named `abc` in the table (and if their is, it will most probably not return the correct result).

Comment: here column name is username and password not abc.